# Jquery not passing array via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send javascript array to php via ajax, but it is not sending, here is my code

```
var ArrayAmounts = new Array();
ArrayAmounts["P1"] = "16150";

$.ajax({
    url:"myajax",
    cache:'false',
    type:'POST',
    data:{Arr:ArrayAmounts},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },error: function(xhr, AjaxOptions, ThrownError){
        ShowMessage(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

but when I am making array like this:

```
 var ArrayAmounts = new Array();
 ArrayAmounts[0] = "16150";
```

it is passing the array, but I want the key as alphanumeric.
please help.

Comment: its an array not an object if you assing to it index it will happen.i think you need object literals

Comment: use an `object` if you want keys to be alphanumeric

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you don't need an array here, you'll need to use an object like this :

```
var Amounts = {};
Amounts["P1"] = "16150";

$.ajax({
    url:"myajax",
    cache:'false',
    type:'POST',
    data:{Arr: Amounts},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },error: function(xhr, AjaxOptions, ThrownError){
        ShowMessage(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: should be `data : { Arr : Amounts }`, not `data : { Arr : ArrayAmounts }`, or even simpler, `data : Amounts`, but yes, that's the way to go

Comment: @JeremyThille Done, Rohit did it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to the kind of data you are sending because as the documentation says:

> "It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's
>   appended to the url for GET-requests. **Object must be Key/Value
>   pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with
>   same key based on the value of the traditional setting**"

[Official documentation for more details](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

you can declare the array like this:
var ArrayAmounts = new Array();
ArrayAmounts = ["16150"];
and then your ajax call work normally

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
var ArrayAmounts = {};
ArrayAmounts.P1 = "16150";

var dataArray = {Arr: ArrayAmounts};

$.ajax({
  url:"myajax",
  cache:'false',
  type:'POST',
  data: dataArray ,
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },error: function(xhr, AjaxOptions, ThrownError){
    ShowMessage(xhr.responseText);
 });
```

Comment: same as Serge K. ans